# EditText crashes the app

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is the XML file of my log in layout right now i have written only the layout part for my application no java coding.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/login_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/tv_login_heading"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_uname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:hint="@string/et_uname_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="@string/tx_color" >


</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/et_pwd_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="@string/tx_color" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textColor="@string/tx_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textColor="@string/tx_color" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@string/tx_color" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/btn_exit"
        android:textColor="@string/tx_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

it produces the following error in log cat when i ran it through my phone micromax canvas a110

```
07-22 15:02:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(26110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.blogspot.pcnlap.sha_login_activity_2/in.blogspot.pcnlap.sha_login_activity_2.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
```

I am thinking that it produces due to edit text at line 24. Anyone have idea to solve this?

Comment: i can't see any problem in your xml, try refresh and clean your xml?

Comment: close your parent linear layout ......at the end

Comment: Try removing `tools:context=".LoginActivity"` and   `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` from your XML layout and apply Clean Build. It should solve the problem..

Comment: Are you closing the root `LinearLayout`?

Comment: -1 for posting only 1 line of log instead of the whole stacktrace.

Comment: I am not sure this is even compiling without closing the root

Comment: Stop down voting guys. He is a beginner with only 1 credit. From where your down votes will be deducted?? :))

Comment: one upvote for beginner.

Comment: i have removed the following still app crashes @YuDroid tools:context=".LoginActivity" and xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: While copy and paste to create a question i have missed the </LinearLayout>. But anyway It crashes the app  @King Cobaraa

Comment: finally this is my app zip file please just check it you can download [SkyDrive](http://sdrv.ms/160c5qb)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your project and run on my system.
As you told its causing crash on EditText
I replaced the         `android:textColor="@string/title_color"` with `android:textColor="@color/title_color`
For that you need to make color.xml file under values folder and put the `title_color` value in this color.xml file.
This solved the problem and I can smoothly run your project.
Hope you got this.
Ask if you have further doubt..

Comment: Thank you Thank  you so much @YuDroid for your response. Minor mistake of setting the color directly in string crashes the program. Oh my God, You saved the day. So I need to use separate Color.xml for colors. Any way I can't vote up now. I'm only 6. Let me explore the world of android

Comment: @AkbarShaEbrahim : You can mark this answer as an Accepted so that other can try this solution